# set Tweet button 'data-text' contents dynamically with javascript, or..?

Tags: javascript, twitter, tweets

Here is functioning code on a form that displays a Tweet button -- the button's on a form that displays several images -- when the user clicks one of the images, it becomes the 'selected' image and the Tweet button is supposed to tweet the selected image's name and url:

```
      <a id="tweetBtnId" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" 
         data-text="Check me out on OurWebSite!"
         data-url=http://$ourSiteURL
         data-via=http://$ourSiteURL data-size="medium" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
     <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
            if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id; 
              js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}
                (document,"script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
```

I have an 'onclick()' handler for the div that displays the image.  When the user clicks one of the images, its div's onclick() handler is called and sets that image to be the 'currentlySelectedImage' on the page -- and the onclick() handler then needs to update the Tweet button's 'data-text' attribute with the name of the just-selected image:

```
          // This is part of the code of the 'onclick()' handler for
          // the image being selected. 
         <script> 
         function handleImageOnClick()
         {
           var myDynamicTweetText = "name of currently-selected image goes here";
           var elem = document.getElementById("tweetBtnId");
           alert("The elem is: " + elem);  // elem IS NULL !!  Dagnabbit.

           // this fails because 'elem' is null
           elem.setAttribute("data-text", myDynamicTweetText);

           // other onclick() code not shown for brevity......
         }
         </script>
```

I need to dynamically change the 'data-text' attribute's value in the Tweet button to be the name of the selected image.  I added the javascript code above which fails-- the 'elem' obtained from the code here:

```
    var elem = document.getElementById("tweetBtnId");
```

is null (I think) because of this line in the Twitter tweet button code above:

```
   if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
```

I'm not sure but it looks like the Twitter Tweet button default script overwrites any attempt 
to add an 'id' attribute to the Tweet button.

You will see that I added the **id="tweetBtnId"** to the Tweet button above so I could get access to the Tweet button in my image-selection onclick() handler above, then set the **'data-text'** to the name of the just-selected image.

I just doubt that Twitter's design goal for the Tweet button was "we're gonna dumb this sucker WAY down, we'll only let these animals choose ONE data-text value - every Tweet button has to have one hard-coded, "Once-on-the-page" data-text attribute - joke's on them if they try to dynamically change the Tweet button's data-text attribute."

I need to get this to work -- any ideas?

Comment: Just confirmed with Firebug -- the id of the Tweet button is 'b', not even a number.  The twitter script is not letting you getElementById() very easily then.

Comment: Wow I can hear the snail outside my window snoring.  Quiet in here today. One SUPER-kludgy workaround would be to create a form with one hidden field and do a form.submit() on it inside my onclick() handler that's called when the user clicks an image.  Then I could set a PHP variable with the name of the 'selected image' and redirect back to the original page, and use the PHP variable for the 'data-text' part of the Tweet button, so when the user tweets the PHP variable has the selected image's name assigned to 'data-text' in the tweet button.  A server round-trip for a tweet!  DAGNABBIT.

Comment: The reason nobody is answering this question is because it is so long and full of code, that is likely to be unrelated to the actual core problem.

Comment: I have this same problem

Comment: @alex_b What problem are you experiencing? It seems to work for me? http://jsbin.com/ivevif/2 (verified with firebug...)

Comment: @wantTheBest Sorry you didn't get more response earlier. Long questions and code aren't the problem (this is a developer site, after all!) it's simply a matter of who is willing to play with the problem at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's going to be the kludgy hidden form/php variable approach for now -- I'll post back if I find a better work-around.

EDIT: the hidden-form/PHP variable solution has beaten the roadblock put up by Twitter's Tweet button -- I can now successfully, dynamically change the Tweet button text at will, anytime based on the user's client-side input.  Per Domenic's astute observation that the question above is too long and has code in it, I'll skip posting the answer here, and I apologize for the length above.

Answer (score 3):

Just put it in a container with a known ID and traverse the document with it:

```
<div id="someIDiKnow">
    <a id="tweetBtnId"...>...</a>
</div>

$("#someIDiKnow a").attr("data-text", "Replacement Text!");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I'm pretty sure you have to reload the twitter script somehow afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery to update the attribute **data-text** by adding an onclick action on the image. If you wanted to include the text inside the actual image tag by adding your own attribute to the  tag, that could be an easy work around to assembling the tweet text.

For example:

```
function updateTweetBtn(obj) {
   $('#someIDiKnow a').attr('data-text', $(this).attr('tweet'));
}

<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" tweet="This is what I want to tweet" onclick="updateTweetBtn(this);" />
<img src="/images/myimage2.jpg" tweet="This is some other text I want to tweet" onclick="updateTweetBtn(this);" />
```

Comment: The problem he's having is that `#tweetBtnId` isn't finding the button!

Comment: Updated my code to use PhonicUK's suggestion. That is a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

using in html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="old text">Tweet</a>
```

I managed to change the 'data-text' with javascript

```
var a = "new text";
document.getElementsByClassName('twitter-share-button')[0].setAttribute("data-text", a);
```

also worked with document.getElementById('twitter') if you add id='twitter' to <a>