# Creating a Tweet from HTML on Page

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to allow a user to create a tweet from content on a page.
I am listing a schedule of events on a page and would like the user to if they like click a button to send out a tweet per event. Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
Event 1, 8:00 AM, Room: 101 [tweet this]
Event 2, 9:00 AM, Room: 102 [tweet this]
Event 3, 10:00 AM, Room: 103 [tweet this]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check official Twitter documentation:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button#ways-to-add-the-tweet-button-to-your-website

You can add Tweet Buttons using javascript and then set attributes for them:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-text="YOUR TEXT">Tweet</a>
```

This might help you - 
[set Tweet button 'data-text' contents dynamically with javascript, or..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676800/set-tweet-button-data-text-contents-dynamically-with-javascript-or)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for but was having a hard time finding!